# real-anylsis: topology, continuous maps, and metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am so lost trying to figure out this question:  I'm not even sure what it is asking, let alone where to start. I basically only have definitions to use; but I can't seem to fit them all together to make this work:

Let $\\X$ be an infinite set, $\\a\in X$, $\Sigma$ be a set of all finite subsets of $\\X$ that do not contain $\\a$.  Prove that $\Sigma$ is the set of all closed sets for some topological structure on $\\X$ and that any two continuous maps of $\\X$ with this topological structure to the same metric space $\\Y$ coincide with each other on $\\a$ if they coincide with each other on every $b \ne a$.

Keep in mind that, even though this is an analysis course, I can only use the topological definitions and theorems from the notes, which include the basics of topological spaces, metric spaces, continuous functions, compact spaces, and connected spaces.  So while there might be some elegant way of doing this with a theorem, I have to resort to using the bare-bones definitions.

Comment: Definitions can differ from classroom to classroom. It would be helpful if you included some of the definitions you have to use about the topological properties you mentioned.

Comment: $\Sigma$ is not the set of closed sets for a topology on $X$, since $X \notin \Sigma$. But just add it in and it will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly it must be checked whether $\Sigma\cup\{X\}$ is closed under finite unions and under arbitrary intersections. Also it must contain the 'empty intersection' wich is set $X$ in this context. See the comment of @GlenMWilson on that.

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be continuous function and let $u:=f(a)\in Y$. In metric space $Y$ singletons are closed and the continuity of $f$ implies that $\{x\in X\mid f(x)=u\}$ is a closed set in $X$. However, the set contains $a$ so does not belong to $\Sigma$. Only one possibility remains: $\{x\in X\mid f(x)=u\}=X$.

We conclude that continuous functions from $X$ to a metric space (or more generally a $T_1$-space, i.e. spaces in which singletons are closed) are constant.